# After issuing the NFT smart contract I made, it cannot be viewed by OpenSea

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft, opensea

```
   // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract  NFTCore is Context, IERC721Errors, ERC165 {
//contract NFTCore is Context, ERC165, IERC721, IERC721Metadata, IERC721Errors {
    using Strings for uint256;

    mapping (address => string) __name;
    mapping (address => string) __symbol;
    mapping (address => mapping(uint256 tokenId => address)) __owners;
    mapping (address => mapping(address owner => uint256)) __balances;
    mapping (address => mapping(uint256 tokenId => address)) __tokenApprovals;
    mapping (address =>  mapping(address owner => mapping(address operator => bool))) __operatorApprovals;


    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 indexed tokenId);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed approved, uint256 indexed tokenId);
    event ApprovalForAll(address indexed owner, address indexed operator, bool approved);

    function init(address contractAddr, string memory _name, string memory _symbol) public{
        __name[contractAddr] = _name;
        __symbol[contractAddr] = _symbol;
    }

    function balanceOf(address contractAddr, address owner) public view returns (uint256) {
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidOwner(address(0));
        }
        return __balances[contractAddr][owner];
    }

    function ownerOf(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) public view returns (address) {
        return _requireOwned(contractAddr, tokenId);
    }

    function name(address contractAddr) public view returns (string memory) {
        return __name[contractAddr];
    }


    function symbol(address contractAddr) public view returns (string memory) {
        return __symbol[contractAddr];
    }

    function tokenURI(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) public view virtual returns (string memory) {
        _requireOwned(contractAddr, tokenId);

        string memory baseURI = _baseURI(contractAddr);
        return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string.concat(baseURI, tokenId.toString()) : "";
    }

    function _baseURI(address contractAddr) internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return "";
    }


    function getApproved(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) public view virtual returns (address) {
        _requireOwned(contractAddr, tokenId);

        return _getApproved(contractAddr, tokenId);
    }

    function approve(address contractAddr, address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual {
        _approve(contractAddr, to, tokenId, _msgSender());
    }

    function _approve(address contractAddr, address to, uint256 tokenId, address auth) internal {
        _approve(contractAddr, to, tokenId, auth, true);
    }

    function _approve(address contractAddr, address to, uint256 tokenId, address auth, bool emitEvent) internal virtual {
        // Avoid reading the owner unless necessary
        if (emitEvent || auth != address(0)) {
            address owner = _requireOwned(contractAddr, tokenId);

            // We do not use _isAuthorized because single-token approvals should not be able to call approve
            if (auth != address(0) && owner != auth && !isApprovedForAll(contractAddr, owner, auth)) {
                revert ERC721InvalidApprover(auth);
            }

            if (emitEvent) {
                emit Approval(owner, to, tokenId);
            }
        }

        __tokenApprovals[contractAddr][tokenId] = to;
    }

    function isApprovedForAll(address contractAddr, address owner, address operator) public view virtual returns (bool) {
        return __operatorApprovals[contractAddr][owner][operator];
    }

    function _requireOwned(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) internal view returns (address) {
        address owner = _ownerOf(contractAddr, tokenId);
        if (owner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721NonexistentToken(tokenId);
        }
        return owner;
    }

    function _ownerOf(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return __owners[contractAddr][tokenId];
    }

     function transferFrom(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public virtual {
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        // Setting an "auth" arguments enables the `_isAuthorized` check which verifies that the token exists
        // (from != 0). Therefore, it is not needed to verify that the return value is not 0 here.
        address previousOwner = _update(contractAddr, to, tokenId, _msgSender());
        if (previousOwner != from) {
            revert ERC721IncorrectOwner(from, tokenId, previousOwner);
        }
    }


    function safeTransferFrom(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        safeTransferFrom(contractAddr, from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data) public virtual {
        transferFrom(contractAddr, from, to, tokenId);
        _checkOnERC721Received(contractAddr, from, to, tokenId, data);
    }

    function _update(address contractAddr, address to, uint256 tokenId, address auth) internal virtual returns (address) {
        address from = _ownerOf(contractAddr, tokenId);

        // Perform (optional) operator check
        if (auth != address(0)) {
            _checkAuthorized(contractAddr, from, auth, tokenId);
        }

        // Execute the update
        if (from != address(0)) {
            // Clear approval. No need to re-authorize or emit the Approval event
            _approve(contractAddr, address(0), tokenId, address(0), false);

            unchecked {
                __balances[contractAddr][from] -= 1;
            }
        }

        if (to != address(0)) {
            unchecked {
                __balances[contractAddr][to] += 1;
            }
        }

        __owners[contractAddr][tokenId] = to;

        emit Transfer(from, to, tokenId);

        return from;
    }

       function _checkAuthorized(address contractAddr, address owner, address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual {
        if (!_isAuthorized(contractAddr, owner, spender, tokenId)) {
            if (owner == address(0)) {
                revert ERC721NonexistentToken(tokenId);
            } else {
                revert ERC721InsufficientApproval(spender, tokenId);
            }
        }
    }

    function _isAuthorized(address contractAddr, address owner, address spender, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (bool) {
        return
            spender != address(0) &&
            (owner == spender || isApprovedForAll(contractAddr, owner, spender) || _getApproved(contractAddr, tokenId) == spender);
    }

    function _getApproved(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return __tokenApprovals[contractAddr][tokenId];
    }

   function setApprovalForAll(address contractAddr,address operator, bool approved) public virtual {
        _setApprovalForAll(contractAddr, _msgSender(), operator, approved);
    }

    function _setApprovalForAll(address contractAddr, address owner, address operator, bool approved) internal virtual {
        if (operator == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidOperator(operator);
        }
        __operatorApprovals[contractAddr][owner][operator] = approved;
        emit ApprovalForAll(owner, operator, approved);
    }


    function _increaseBalance(address contractAddr, address account, uint128 value) internal virtual {
        unchecked {
            __balances[contractAddr][account] += value;
        }
    }

    function _mint(address contractAddr,address to, uint256 tokenId) public {
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        address previousOwner = _update(contractAddr, to, tokenId, address(0));
        if (previousOwner != address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidSender(address(0));
        }
    }

    function _safeMint(address contractAddr,address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        _safeMint(contractAddr, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    function _safeMint(address contractAddr, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data) internal virtual {
        _mint(contractAddr, to, tokenId);
        _checkOnERC721Received(contractAddr, address(0), to, tokenId, data);
    }

function _transfer(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        if (to == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721InvalidReceiver(address(0));
        }
        address previousOwner = _update(contractAddr, to, tokenId, address(0));
        if (previousOwner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721NonexistentToken(tokenId);
        } else if (previousOwner != from) {
            revert ERC721IncorrectOwner(from, tokenId, previousOwner);
        }
    }

    function _safeTransfer(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        _safeTransfer(contractAddr, from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    function _safeTransfer(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data) internal virtual {
        _transfer(contractAddr, from, to, tokenId);
        _checkOnERC721Received(contractAddr, from, to, tokenId, data);
    }

    function _checkOnERC721Received(address contractAddr, address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes memory data) private {
        if (to.code.length > 0) {
            try IERC721Receiver(to).onERC721Received(_msgSender(), from, tokenId, data) returns (bytes4 retval) {
                if (retval != IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector) {
                    revert ERC721InvalidReceiver(to);
                }
            } catch (bytes memory reason) {
                if (reason.length == 0) {
                    revert ERC721InvalidReceiver(to);
                } else {
                    /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
                    assembly {
                        revert(add(32, reason), mload(reason))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function _burn(address contractAddr, uint256 tokenId) internal {
        address previousOwner = _update(contractAddr, address(0), tokenId, address(0));
        if (previousOwner == address(0)) {
            revert ERC721NonexistentToken(tokenId);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "./NFTCore.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";

contract NFTSampleis is Context, ERC165, IERC721, IERC721Metadata, IERC721Errors {
   
   address private _thisAddr;
   NFTCore private _nftCore;
   uint256 private _tokenId = 0;

   constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, address _nftCoreAddress) {
        _thisAddr = address(this);
        _nftCore = NFTCore(_nftCoreAddress);
        _nftCore.init(_thisAddr, _name, _symbol);
   }

    function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) public view virtual override(ERC165, IERC165) returns (bool) {
        return
            interfaceId == type(IERC721).interfaceId ||
            interfaceId == type(IERC721Metadata).interfaceId ||
            super.supportsInterface(interfaceId);
    }

    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return _nftCore.balanceOf(_thisAddr, owner);
    }

    function ownerOf(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address owner) {
        return _nftCore.ownerOf(_thisAddr, tokenId);
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId, bytes calldata data) external {
        _nftCore.safeTransferFrom(_thisAddr, from, to, tokenId, data);   
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external {
        _nftCore.safeTransferFrom(_thisAddr, from, to, tokenId);  
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external {
        _nftCore.transferFrom(_thisAddr, from, to, tokenId);
    }

    function approve(address to, uint256 tokenId) external {
        _nftCore.approve(_thisAddr, to, tokenId);
    }

    function setApprovalForAll(address operator, bool approved) external {
        _nftCore.setApprovalForAll(_thisAddr, operator, approved);
    }

    function getApproved(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address operator) {
        return _nftCore.getApproved(_thisAddr, tokenId);
    }

    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator) external view returns (bool) {
        return _nftCore.isApprovedForAll(_thisAddr, owner, operator);
    }

    function mint(address to) public {
        _nftCore._mint(_thisAddr, to, _tokenId++);
    }

    function name() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _nftCore.name(_thisAddr);
    }

    function symbol() external view returns (string memory) {
        return _nftCore.symbol(_thisAddr);
    }

     function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (string memory) {
        return _nftCore.tokenURI(_thisAddr,tokenId);
     }
}
```

I made a contract called NFTCore and NFTSample.

The NFTCore contract is a real ERC721 interface implementation.
NFTSample receives the address of NFTCore, and the NFT functionality is activated by NFTCore.

I think since it complies with ERC721, the NFT should be seen when opening normally, but it's not.

Is there something wrong with my contract?
Thank you in advance for your response.

opensea link
https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/unidentified-contract-327aa12d-2101-430a-8976-0fe7